# Can I embed a twitter feed in my email?

Tags: email, twitter, widget, embed

I'm about to send out an email campaign to my clients. The email will be sent in HTML format, and I wanted to embed a twitter feed in my email, similar to the twitter widgets you see embedded in blogs and websites everywhere. When I copy and paste the code generated through the twitter website, my email doesn't render anything :(

Any ideas if this is possible? Thanks! Here's the code twitter generated:

`<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'faves',
  rpp: 5,
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'The best of Twitter according to',
  subject: 'My Tweets',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8540c2',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#43c43f'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('maryamKE').start();
</script>`

Comment: No Javascript, but you can render it into the html. If you can convert it to an RSS feed, there are a a few RSS -> email tools out there. Here is [Campaign Monitor's](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/rss-to-email/), and here is [Mailchimp's](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/what-is-an-rss-to-email-campaign-and-how-to-i-set-one-up/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard for HTML email, and most email clients sensibly reject JavaScript.  I recommend you link to a page on your web site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to accomplish this with the embeds provided directly from Twitter.

This was a need I also had and created a service that makes it extremely easy: https://www.widgmail.com/