# Can you embed a Facebook or Twitter feed in a html emailer?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a twitter feed in my email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310778/can-i-embed-a-twitter-feed-in-my-email)

I know that it is a no no to embed forms within a html email, but what about displaying Twitter and facebook feeds?  Is this possible ?  Thanks

Comment: You could certainly pull the feeds before generating the email and embed them there as normal HTML, but no, there'd be no way to embed a dynamic feed into an email.